# Redirection to a page by clicking href link

Tags: angular

A simple hello world with angular links on the page and once clicked redirect to another page.

Comment: can you add a bit more information?

Comment: Actually  im learning angular

Answer (score -1):

**HTML Routing**

```
<a href="/dashboard.html">Dashboard</a>
```

**Angular Routing**

```
<a [routerLink]="'/dashboard'">Dashboard</a>
```

You just have to use **routerLink** attribute instead of href.